# How to drag items between 2 sorted lists with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, sorting

I'm trying to implement drag/drop/sort between 2 list elements:

```
<ul id="first">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="second">
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Basically I just want to be able to pass items between the lists and sort the items in each list. What's the simplest way to implement this using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#first').sortable( { connectWith : '#second' });
    $('#second').sortable( { connectWith : '#first' });
  });
</script>
```

I've noticed that an earlier version of jQuery-UI (1.6rc5) I tried this with didn't accept the css selector for connectWith. I threw a curve and got it to work with actual jQuery elements instead:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#first').sortable( { connectWith : $('#second') });
    $('#second').sortable( { connectWith : $('#first') });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

[jQueryUI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists) - this is exactly what you want.